# Fragment failed to load from a notification

Tags: android, xml, firebase, android-layout

I try to implement a simple notification for new event happen on my app but when i try to open my app from a notification clicked app crash.
It's said this error

```
Process: it.breakingbad.crimegoaway, PID: 13239
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.breakingbad.crimegoaway/it.breakingbad.crimegoaway.NavBarActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in it.breakingbad.crimegoaway:layout/activity_nav_bar: Binary XML file line #19 in it.breakingbad.crimegoaway:layout/content_nav_bar: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3520)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5580)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5486)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
```

i think the error is in my navbarActivity in the onCreate on this line  `ActivityNavBarBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());`

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

        try {
            binding = ActivityNavBarBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            // ... rest of body of onCreateView() ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "onCreateView", e);
        }


        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarNavBar.toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        // Get Username and Email TextViews
        TextView userName = headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_username);
        TextView userEmail = headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_email);

        // set user name and email
        userName.setText("Username");
        Users.writeUsernameNavBar(userName);
        userEmail.setText(Users.getCurrentUser().getCurrentUser().getEmail());

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_add_alert, R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_view_alerts, R.id.nav_my_alerts, R.id.nav_exit)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_nav_bar);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        //work manager declaration if not present
        if(getIntent().getExtras() == null) {

            WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG_ALERTS);

            WorkRequest workAlertRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(AlertCheckerWorker.class, 4, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    /*.setInitialDelay(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)*/
                    .addTag(TAG_ALERTS).build();
            WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueue(workAlertRequest);

            WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG_COMMENTS);

            WorkRequest workCommentRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(CommentCheckerWorker.class, 4, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    /*.setInitialDelay(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)*/
                    .addTag(TAG_COMMENTS).build();
            WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueue(workCommentRequest);

        }

        //used for notification "re-routing"
        if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(bundle.getParcelable("alert") != null) {
                Alert alert = bundle.getParcelable("alert");

                DetailAlertFragment fragment_alert = new DetailAlertFragment();
                fragment_alert.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_nav_bar, fragment_alert);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

the notification are cath from here

```
                            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavBarActivity.class);
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putParcelable("alert", tempAlert);
                            resultIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                            //resultIntent.putExtra("alert", tempAlert);

                            Log.d("AlertCheckerWorker", "doWork: " + tempAlert.toString());
                            // Create the TaskStackBuilder and add the intent, which inflates the back stack
                            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
                            stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
                            // Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
                            int notificationId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() + new Random().nextInt());

                            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(notificationId,
                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.category_crime)
                                    .setContentTitle("Alert Title: " + tempAlert.getTitle())
                                    .setContentText("Description: " + tempAlert.getDescription())
                                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                    .build();
                            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

passed to navbaractivity and after passed to the detailalertfragment

```
            alert = getArguments().getParcelable("alert");

            //GraphicTools.showToast(getContext(),alert.toString());

            alertTitleTextView.setText(alert.getTitle());

            alertAddCommentImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(alertAddCommentEditText.getText().toString().length()>0){
                        Comment comment=new Comment(alertAddCommentEditText.getText().toString(), Timestamp.now(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        Comments.addCommentInFirestore(alert.getDocumentId(),comment);
                        alertAddCommentEditText.setText("");
                    }else {
                        alertAddCommentEditText.setError("Add a comment");
                    }
                }
            });

            alertDescriptionTextView.setText(alert.getDescription());
```

[here i put a simple schema to understand how work my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srlpr.png)

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600** (six hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).